# PHP error on publish/edit screen - certain channels only

Tags: php-errors, publish-layout

On a site running EE v.2.2.1, I've encountered an error that affects the display of the top tab section of the publish/edit screen. It appears to be occurring in only two channels out of about a dozen on the site.

I'm attaching a screenshot that shows the garbled screen and the error message, which is:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   field_visibility Filename: content/publish.php Line Number: 71

[image]

Line 71 in the file (expressionengine/views/content.publish.php) reads as follows:

```
<img src="<?=$cp_theme_url?>images/<?= ($field['field_visibility'] == "y") ? 'open_eye' : 'closed_eye' ?>.png" alt="<?=lang('delete')?>" width="15" height="15" />
```

Notes:

I built this site for a client a number of years ago and upgraded it to EE 2 in 2011, but I haven't really touched it since then. So I don't know what changes may have been made in the interim.

The only thing I do know is that the hosting company moved the site to a new server a couple of months ago. Of course, that may not be relevant -- or maybe it is.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this? Thanks!

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this looks like the publish layout got corrupted. This was fixed a number of versions back, but was common in the earlier EE releases.

To fix, you can simply re-save the layout, and it should reset you back to normal. You'll, of course, have to reconfigure and hidden fields or re-ordering that you had done previously.

[image]